# Customising the template for a CheckboxSelectMultiple widget: Can other object properties be passed as attributes?

Tags: forms, widget, django-crispy-forms

I have a model form that represents the choices for a ManyToMany field as checkboxes.
The two related models are as follows:

**Passenger Model:**

```
class Passenger(models.Model):
    ... attributes etc .....
    trip_addons = models.ManyToManyField(AddOn, blank=True)
```

**'Add on' Model:**

```
class Addon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    image_thumb = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

But rather than rendering the default html checkboxes, I would like present the 'addon' options a little more like the 3rd example 'Choose your main dish' in [this](https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-checkbox-list) link, with the picture and short description in addition to the name.

I have created my own template to be used by the widget and that works. I just would like to know if can pass the description, image and price data to these templates?

**forms.py**

```
class CustomCheckbox(forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    """
    Creates a custom checkbox select widget that subclasses Django's
    CheckboxSelectMultiple and customises it with a different template
    """

    template_name = 'bookings/forms/checkbox_select.html'
    option_template_name = 'bookings/forms/checkbox_option.html'.
```

and in the Meta for my Modelform:

```
widgets = {
            "trip_addons": CustomCheckbox(),
        }
```

Comment: Been checking around. How should these templates look like? Any link to that. I mean what variables will allow accessing the queryset and choices in the HTML template?

Answer (score 0):

I acheived what I wanted to acheive by overriding the create_option method in the CustomCheckbox class and using the value passed in the parameters to retrieve a queryset from the database. This was added to the dictionary as an additional attribute.